# I want setup android project on netbeans using Google Java Api Client?

Tags: android, netbeans-7, google-api-java-client

I am new to Android and I want to develop one small application using Google Java Api Client inside Netbeans, which I already developed on JAVA using swing and it is working correctly.

My netbeans is ready to work for Android But I coudn't figured out how to setup the android project to use the Google Java API client.

Can someone please provide me the detail tutorial to setup the Android project using Google Java Api Client?

I am not sure may I need to do additional processing on google java api client library which is downloded form [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list).

My Android setup is working correctly on Netbeans.

Can someone please provide me a detail explanation on this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Put JAR files from a library that you want to use into lib folder of your android project and you will be able to use it and it will be bundled into .apk too. I am assuming that you have an android project (using nbandroid plugin. I am not sure about maven archetype for android development).

-Radim